# Map of Poland and routing engine is missing A1 motorroad

Tags: here-api

Our team has noticed that we are missing the bypass of Częstochowa (50.8118° N, 19.1203° E) which is a newly built A1 motor road. It is represented as an unfinished road. Most importantly routing engine is not aware of this route.

**HERE**

[image: Current Map HERE]

**TomTom**

[image: Current Map TomTom]

**Google**

[image: Current Map Google]

**My question is when may we expect an update to the routing engine?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly report map corrections and additions using our map edit tool via reporting the issue there and later track the issue by following below

> https://mapcreator.here.com

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a quick response!